# Can i get IP Address of DOS 6.22 Operating System?

Tags: c, sockets, dos

I am working with DOS 6.22 and I need to extract the IP address of my system using a C program.

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    struct ifreq ifr;
    char array[] = "eth0";

    n = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    //Type of address to retrieve - IPv4 IP address
    ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;
    //Copy the interface name in the ifreq structure
    strncpy(ifr.ifr_name , array , IFNAMSIZ - 1);
    ioctl(n, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr);
    close(n);
    //display result
    printf("IP Address is %s - %s\n" , array , inet_ntoa(( (struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr )->sin_addr) );
    return 0;
}
```

But the error error is, it does not identify the `SIOCGIFADDR` variable, even using all header files.

Does DOS support networking?

Comment: Are you still there? Have your questions been answered?

Comment: Sorry, but your edit changed the question too much and invalidated the answers. You should post a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MS-DOS (which I presume you're relating to, as 6.22 was one of (if not the) last versions to be published; there's a **lot** of DOSes) never had a native IP stack.

So there's **no** unified way to query IP "of a system" (or in fact, any networking-related thing) under MS-DOS, because MS-DOS never had any networking built-in, so as a system, it didn't have an IP address. Maybe a single executable built up an Ethernet, and atop of that, an IP connectivity, or maybe a resident pseudodriver did, but not the operating system as is.

This means you're using one of the *hundreds* of third-party IP implementations that existed for MS-DOS. You're not telling us which, so we can't help you.

Now, you get errors when compiling about undefined constants – you're probably not using the right `#include`s, or haven't configured your compiler to look into the right directories for headers.

In any case, I'd recommend getting a bit knowledgeable about C and about MS-DOS, and, most importantly, figure out which IP implementation you're using, and where to get documentation for that.

Comment: By the way, asking Google for "MSDOS TCP/IP" lead to *dozens* of results telling you that, no, MSDOS did not have networking support.

Comment: And more importantly, using a modern operating system. Almost anything (Linux, Windows, OS X, QNX, FreeBSD , or whatever) is better than DOS these days.   Please don't use DOS.

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly sure DOS does not support IP networking natively. If I remember correctly (this stuff was *many* years ago, so I may remember wrong) there were some TCP/IP stacks available for DOS back in the day - maybe you can dig up some of them and use them.

But really, why are you using an obsolete OS like this for anything in 2016?

Comment: I'm really intrigued by that question, too.